# SELECT WHERE variable not working

Tags: php, mysql, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I'm working on a table using jqGrid PHP and I'm trying to set my select statement to `SELECT` with a variable for the `WHERE` section.  I've got the code below:

```
$groupid = isset($_SESSION['group']) ? $_SESSION['group'] : 1;
$query = "SELECT MEMBER_ID, FirstName, LastName, Email, Street1, City, State, Zip, Phone, MemberSince, ExpDate, group_GROUP_ID, membership_MEM_ID FROM member WHERE group_GROUP_ID = $groupid";
$grid->SelectCommand = $query;
```

In this case, `$groupid` is 9, and when running a manual query with 9, 4 results come back.

The above doesn't work, but when setting `$query` equal to the below (hard-coding it in), the table returns the 4 results as expected.

```
$query = "SELECT MEMBER_ID, FirstName, LastName, Email, Street1, City, State, Zip, Phone, MemberSince, ExpDate, group_GROUP_ID, membership_MEM_ID FROM member WHERE group_GROUP_ID = 9";
```

I've tried all the different ways to concatenate it, but none work.  Below is what I've tried (shortened down):

```
"... WHERE group_GROUP_ID = " . $groupid . "";

"... WHERE group_GROUP_ID = '" . $groupid . "'";

"... WHERE group_GROUP_ID = '$groupid'";
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: so did you do a `var_dump($query)` to see what you really built? is `$groupid` what you think it should be?

Answer (score 2):

This happens to a lot of people, but after 3 hours of tinkering, I've found the problem.

Since $groupid is based off of a session variable, and the php script doesn't call `session_start()`, the session variable isn't available.

I called `session_start()` at the top of the script and my first solution works perfectly.

Sorry for answering myself!